# How many (direct) children do people think Adam & Eve had or Adam had?

Tags: genesis, creation, genealogy

This question relates to any history related a question raised by
Gen 5:4  **After Seth was born, Adam lived 800 years and had other sons and daughters.**

The statement that Adam had other sons and daughters implies that he and Eve had other sons and daughters in addition to Abel, Cain, and Seth although it only states that Adam had the additional children.
So what if anything can the history of the text and its interpretations tell us about how many (1st generation) children Adam & Eve or Adam had?

I also recall researching some references where Eve was said to have other Sons so that is why I include "Adam & Eve" in the scope of my question.

I anticipate that answers may require reference into extra-biblical texts and traditions although the scriptures themselves is where it begins for me.

I'm interested in compiling the best references whether direct or indirect on subject that would allow me to justify a "best guess" answer. 
Combining the implications of the scriptural record with other ancient texts for instance would be welcome.

Comment: A [related](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42737) question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *[Chronographies](http://www.scribd.com/document/30161469)* of [George Kedrenos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Kedrenos) (page 95) and [Dorotheos of Monemvasia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Dorotheos_of_Monemvasia), they had sixty children, 33 sons and 27 daughters. [Methodius of Olympus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methodius_of_Olympus), however, spoke of one hundred pairs of twins, male and female, each marrying one's sibling upon reaching maturity. [Cain and Abel's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain_and_Abel) twin sisters were [Calmana and Delbora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balbira_and_Kalmana), while [Seth's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seth) was called *Asvama*. [Pseudo-Philo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Philo)'s *[Biblical Antiquities](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/bap/bap17.htm)*, on the other hand, mention twenty offspring, twelve men and eight women.